# How can I add two limit switches in this circuit?

Tags: dc-motor

Here is schematic for control of rotating direction of DC motor using two relays:

[image]

How can I add two limit switches here?
When limit is reached I want to stop motor and of course to be able to move it in opposite direction :)

Comment: Put your forward limit switch in series with the coil on the top relay and similar for the other direction on the bottom relay.

Comment: What a puzzle !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9kkD3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You have supplied a wiring diagram rather than a schematic. Schematics are better for demonstrating circuit *intent*. Here is one which may suit your purpose.

RLY1 is ON/OFF control. RLY2 is FWD/REV control. Motor is assumed to run CW when top terminal is positive.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I need. Sorry because I didn't give positive vote, I don't have sufficient reputation so I can't do it :(